# Using <select> tags with a Switch statment (Java and HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, calculator

I am creating a calculator for a game and I want to use a drop down menu to select a value in a switch statement; although it doesn't seem to be working, it always returns 0. Can anyone see where I went wrong? Also I am fairly new to java and html so sorry if there is a dumb mistake.

http://jsfiddle.net/1r177khr/

Here is my html:

```
<form onsubmit="return calcDarkTroops(0);" style="display: inline;">
<!-- Title of Form /--> <font>Level</font> 
<!-- Gets Input /-->
<select id="minionlevel_input">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<!-- Calls 'calcDarkTroops' /-->
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calcDarkTroops();">
<!-- Outputs result /--> <span id="minioncost_result"> = 0 Dark Elixer</span>
```

Here is my Java:

```
calcDarkTroops = function () {
 var minionlevel = Number(document.getElementById("minionlevel_input").value);
 String maxString;
 switch (minionlevel) {
     case 1:
         maxString = "200,000";
         break;
     case 2:
         maxString = "190,000";
         break;
     case 3:
         maxString = "170,000";
         break;
     case 4:
         maxString = "140,000";
         break;
     case 5:
         maxString = "100,000";
         break;
     case 6:
         maxString = "0";

     document.getElementById("minioncost_result").innerHTML = "= " + Math.round(maxString * 100) / 100 + " Dark Elixer";

                        }
```

Comment: Console says calcDarkTroops(); is not defined.

Comment: Your Java looks like javascript

Comment: `String maxString` -> `var maxString`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tdnLx83h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the value attribute to your select option and also consider providing default option,

```
<select id="minionlevel_input">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/s6j6676c/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form style="display: inline;">
<!-- Title of Form /--> <font>Level</font> 
<!-- Gets Input /-->
<select id="minionlevel_input">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<!-- Calls 'calcDarkTroops' /-->
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="return calcDarkTroops(document.getElementById('minionlevel_input').value)">
<!-- Outputs result /--> <span id="minioncost_result"> = 0 Dark Elixer</span>

<script>
 function calcDarkTroops(minionlevel) {
   var maxString;
   switch (minionlevel) {
     case '1':
         maxString = "200,000";
         break;
     case '2':
         maxString = "190,000";
         break;
     case '3':
         maxString = "170,000";
         break;
     case '4':
         maxString = "140,000";
         break;
     case '5':
         maxString = "100,000";
         break;
     case '6':
         maxString = "0";
         break;    
   }
     document.getElementById("minioncost_result").innerHTML = "= " + Math.round(parseInt(maxString) * 100) / 100 + " Dark Elixer";
```

}

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1r177khr/13/)